# Sitecore 8.2 publishing service not working

Tags: sitecore, publishing, sitecore8, sitecore8.2

For sitecore publishing service I have followed the steps from  https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2016/09/02/setting-up-sitecore-publishing-service and Sitecore. But I am getting below error:

HTTP Error 500.19 – Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Module  IIS Web Core

Notification    Unknown

Handler Not yet determined

Error Code  0x8007000d

Config Error

Config File \?\C:\sitecorepublishing\web.config

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AspNetCoreModule has to be installed on the server and is part of the ASP.NET Core Server Hosting Bundle.